# Change Custom List View from MainActivity to ExampleFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have simple project in android, I want to add custom list view in my fragment, I find example custom list view on internet, but it is located in Main Activity, I do not know how can I add this custom list view from Main Activity to Example Fragment. Any idea?

**ExampleFragment:**

```
   class ExampleFragment : Fragment() {
   var listView: ListView? = null
   private var mTitle = arrayOf("Facebook", "Whatsapp", "Twitter", 
   "Instagram", "Youtube")
   private var mDescription = arrayOf("Facebook Description", "Whatsapp 
   Description", "Twitter Description", "Instagram Description", 
   "Youtube Description")
   private var images = intArrayOf(R.drawable.ic_facebook, 
        R.drawable.ic_whatsapp,
        R.drawable.ic_twitter,
        R.drawable.ic_instagram,
        R.drawable.ic_youtube)

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_example)
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView)
    // now create an adapter class
    val adapter = MyAdapter(this, mTitle, mDescription, images)
    listView!!.adapter = adapter
    // there is my mistake...
    // now again check this..

    // now set item click on list view
    listView!!.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
        if (position == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this@ExampleFragment, "Facebook Description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if (position == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this@ExampleFragment, "Whatsapp Description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if (position == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this@ExampleFragment, "Twitter Description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if (position == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this@ExampleFragment, "Instagram Description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if (position == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this@ExampleFragment, "Youtube Description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    // so item click is done now check list view
}
 internal inner class MyAdapter(context: ProfilFragment, private var rTitle: Array<String>, private var rDescription: Array<String>, var rImgs: IntArray) : ArrayAdapter<String?>(context, R.layout.row, R.id.textView1, rTitle) {
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val layoutInflater = applicationContext.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false)
        val images = row.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)
        val myTitle = row.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView1)
        val myDescription = row.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2)

        // now set our resources on views
        images.setImageResource(rImgs[position])
        myTitle.text = rTitle[position]
        myDescription.text = rDescription[position]
        return row
    }
}
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_example, container,false)
```

Comment: I would recommend having a look at some tutorials on fragments, there really is no difference in implementation if you understand the fragment lifecycle etc.

Comment: I look , but I did not get it

Comment: Then I would recommend maybe asking a question about what you don't understand? Saying "I just don't get it" doesn't show much effort in my opinion.